# To do encryption for postgresql db backup

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-12

Is this possible when someone takes backup of my postgres db it should be in encrypted form(**i.e.if root user will access from command line(pg_dump) or from any tool**). and how we can decrypt that backup.if its possible please help me out.

Comment: You could pipe the output of `pg_dump` into your favorite encryption program.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible ...

Yes.

> ... when someone takes backup of my postgres db ...

Question:
Why would anyone *other* than you (and your team) be taking a backup of your database?
[I'm guessing] It's *your* responsibility to keep the database secure, recoverable and performant, so *nobody else* should be monkeying about with it or taking copies of it.

> ... it should be in encrypted form ...

pg_dump produces a file.
Encrypt that file, which you can in a "one-liner", something like this:

```
pg_dump ... | tar -czf file.tar.gz
```

> ... and how we can decrypt that backup.

Exactly as you say - decrypt the [encrypted] backup file and restore what comes out of that, something like this:

```
tar -xzf file.tar.gz | psql
```

This assumes that you're extracting a single, "plain" format file, rather than the [faster] directory-based backup options.  I suspect that to protect the latter, you'd have to do the backup and then combine/encrypt the resulting files in a second step (and, of course,  the *reverse* for restoring them).

Comment: Does `tar -czf` actually encrypt anything?

Comment: Good Catch!  "-z" only compresses the archive!  
"-j", "-lzip", "-lzma" and "-lzop" are the encryption options.

Comment: Nope, none of the encrypt the archive.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply but due security policies of client no one can take plain backup.